# How To Read ".XML" File Offline Using Pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, feed, offline

I am trying to read a `.xml` file that is a feed using pure JavaScript in my PC to show data on my browser. You can view my [**feed.xml**](https://shrib.com/xMQBq7HOBOHqx1Y) file online that I saved from [**GoogleBlogXMLFeed**](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/?redirect=false&max-results=500). I can read that online via `JSON` but I want to read it offline after saving them in my file `feed.xml` in my PC. Is this possiable or not? If yes then any guideline...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the "user" local file system from a web page. This would be a serious security issue (do you want web apps to be able to access files on your PC while you are browsing?).

If you have the file on the same server with your app you can access it, just make sure you have the file extension in your mime-types.

----- adding the code based on comments -------

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "feed.xml", 
  success: function(xml){ 
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        title = $xml.find( "title" ).text();
    console.log(title);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have this `feed.xml` file in my same folder where I have `index.html` file. I want to read `feed.xml` file from `index.html` file. That's it. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible if you open the index.html in a "server" (so you if you are using IIS or Wamp or something). Do you open your index.html file as "http://localhost/index.html" or "C:\something\index.html"? It will only work if you are on localhost/something... and then you can just do an ajax request to http://localhost/feed.xml

Comment: Yes, I am opening `index.html` in browser like "C:\something\index.html" and also able to view fully formatted feed at "C:\something\feed.xml" in my browser then I want to get data from `feed.xml` file and want to show in `index.html`. Can you share any DEMO or Example for AJAX...???

Comment: It will not work that way, you NEED to have it opened as a web application not as a file. Currently your index.html is just opened as a normal file. Add that folder to your IIS or install wamp/xamp to be able to open that index.html file as http://localhost/index.html not as a file. After that, you can just do [code] $.ajax({url: "feed.xml", success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }}); [/code]

Comment: Can you edit your answer with code as per my desire like I want to pick every post title from my `feed.xml` so I can select as the ANSWER?

Comment: Your question was about something else :) but OK...

Comment: My question is this what I am asking you in comments. I just want to read it as feed means to pic titles, images, content, links etc directly as object.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load feed.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` :-(

Comment: I told you 3 times that you need to run it as a web application so it will need to be "http.... " (http://localhost/index.html). You are doing it as C:\something\index.html. Please install wamp/xamp or load it in IIS.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this error? I am able to edit my `Feed.XML` file also but dont want to use any SERVER/HOST...???

Comment: NO... you need to have some kind of server. there are multiple options there.

Comment: Thanks for helping me till here. Will try to find out any other solution but I cant use any SERVER/HOST...

Comment: I just tested it and its working in FireFox not in Chrome and its ok. But still I am seeing blank POPUP. I used `alert(title);` instead of `console.log(title);`...